# Parsing XML with AJAX : undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I am parsing xml and what I want is to return xml after parsing it. I can't get image. Can you help me ? My code below or http://jsfiddle.net/4DejY/1/:

HTML

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search..." id="ds-canho">
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.mobile.loading("show");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url=%27http://saigonpearl.info/trang-chu.html%27%20and%20xpath=%22//td[@class=%27table3%27]/table/tr[2]/td/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/a[contains(@href,%20%27http%27)]%20|%20//div[@class=%27tindang%27]/h3%20|%20//div[@class=%27detailsR%27]/p%22%20%20&diagnostics=true',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });

    function parseXml(xml) {
        var gia, img, title;
        $(xml).find('p').each(function () {
            gia = $(this).html();

            $("ul#ds-canho").append('<li><img src="' + img + '">' + title + '<p id="gia"> ' + gia + '</p></li>')
            $('ul#ds-canho').listview('refresh');
            console.log(this);
        });

        $(xml).find('h3').each(function () {
            title = $(this).find('h3').text();

            console.log(this);
        });

        $(xml).find("img").each(function () {
            img = $(this).find('src').text();
            console.log(this);
            $.mobile.loading("hide");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/4DejY/)**

The issue is that you declare `title` but you never assign it a value, then you try to concatenate it into the HTML. The title can be found by doing:

```
title = $(this).prev('h3').text();
```

This works because the title is a `<h3>` and is a sibling of the `<p>` which is `this`, so you can use jQuery's [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the previous sibling.